# How to overwrite files on iphone file directory?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, replace, copy-paste, paste

My old question was a bit roughly explained, so I will try it again. I want to develope an app, which simply overwrites files in the iPhone file directory with my own files, but I don´t know the code for the overwriting part.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can not overwrite files in the iPhones file directory. The only part you as a developer can access for read and write is your [application's document directory](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html).

Comment: But somehow all this Cydia Tweaks also overwrite existing files. How do they do that?

Comment: Then you should jailbreak your iphone to install cydia. However Im not familiar with the process of developing apps for jailbroken iphones.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just delete existing files so that you can put new ones?

Comment: Users can do it manually but I want to develop this application to make it easier.